# Trouble passing a List object as hidden variable from JSP to a servlet

Tags: spring, list, servlets, jstl, hidden-field

I am trying to  render a list of objects in my controller  which are passed from jsp as hidden varaiable.

Here is my code

**in my employeeResults.jsp**

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="employee"  >
<tr>
<td>${employee.empId}</td>
<td>${employee.empName}</td>
<td>${employee.empEmail}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach> 
<form  method="POST"  action="downloadCSV.html" >
<input type="hidden" id="empList" name="empList" value="${list}"/>
<input type="submit" name="download" value="Download"/>
</form>
```

**In my Controller**

// method call for employee search

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", params = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView lookupEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command") Employee emp) {

String lookupEmpId = null;
if(emp.getEmpId()!= null)
lookupEmpId = emp.getEmpId();
String[] line = lookupEmpId.split("\n");
List<String> eIds = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String i: line){
eIds.add(i);
}

List<Employee> listEmp = employeeDAO.searchRecords(eIds); 
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("lookupResults");  
model.addObject("list",listEmp);
    return model;

}// addContact()

  @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void downloadCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws       IOException {

    String empList = request.getParameter("empList");
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(empList.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    -----
    }
```

when I run  empList is returning a sting in array format , but I would like to do is to get the Employee object list  from jsp .

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The HTTP protocol doesn't know and care about Java. HTTP request parameters are Strings, and there is no way to make them Employee objects. HTTP doesn't even have the concept of object. Why are you passing Employees from the browser to the server. Employee information should be stored in your database. You should only need to send the IDs of the employees to have the server get them from the database.

Comment: You can edit your question to include that extra code. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @ JB Nizet : Actually I am  displaying employee results in jsp and I have download CSV option in same jsp to get the results into CSV file.  so i am trying to send the list from jsp to controller.

Comment: So, when the user clicks the download link, get back thoe enployeee results from the database again, the same way you did to display them on the JSP, but generate a CSV instead of an HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct way to save the object in hidden fields.

Look at the source code in the browser, It might display something like that is default `toString()` representation of the `List<Employee>`.

```
<input type="hidden" id="empList" name="empList" value="[pkg.Employee@7b9bd73]"/>
```

---

Set it in session as attribute in method `lookupEmployee()` and get it back in `downloadCSV()` method.

Sample code:

```
public ModelAndView lookupEmployee(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute("command") Employee emp) {
     ...
     List<Employee> listEmp = employeeDAO.searchRecords(eIds); 
     request.getSession().setAttribute("empList", listEmp);
     ...
}

public void downloadCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     List<Employee> empList = (List<Employee>)request.getSession().getAttribute("empList");
     ...
}
```

---

#### EDIT

> I don't want to use session scope for this, I am looking for any other alternative option

Use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string to transfer an Object between server and client.

Use any JSON parsing library such as [GSON library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to form a JAVA object from JSON string and vice-verse.

Please have a look at this [Example](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples)

Comment: I just tried this way but empList is returning null

Comment: save it in session as attribute and get from session in deonloadCSV() method.

Comment: Thank you it worked ! but I don't want to use session scope for this, I am looking for any other alternative option.

Comment: Use some third party cache such as Infinispan, EHCache etc. Use GSON or JSON and send parsed JSON string to the client and send back to the server.